# Can i turn an HTML <map> <area> grayscale with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, area

Is an `<area>` element grayscalable through CSS?

```js
$(".shape").on("mouseenter", function(evt) {
  $(this).addClass("bw")
})
```

```css
.bw {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/5611472-simple-images.png" class="image" height="500px" width="500px" usemap="#simple">

<map class="map" name="simple">
  <area class="poly shape" coords="87,64,85,170,205,174,205,64,143,64,109,64" shape="poly">
  <area class="circle shape" coords="419,258,123" shape="circle">
</map>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cva0qctg/7/)

Comment: No, what you are trying to do cannot be done.

Comment: Relevant: [Apply css to AREA MAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026421/apply-css-to-area-map) and [Visible Area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag)

Comment: Short answer No, Long answer, with SVG yes - Is this the effect you are trying to achieve [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/cva0qctg/78/) ?